# C# scope and visual studio debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, scope

While debugging C# code with VS2010 I test curious behavior that i cannot explain.
With the very simplified code below :

```
public void Go()
    {
        var test = new Random().Next(10) % 2 == 0; // Simulate various cases

        var qry = new[] { "bla", "ble", "bli", }.ToList(); // Get whole list        

        //string myString; // If declare out of scope OK
        if (test) // BreakPoint here and dragNDrop on next line
        {
            var myString = "bli"; // declare and instanciate in scope => NullReferenceException 

            qry = qry.Where( item => item == myString ).ToList(); // filter the list
        }
    }
```

When I try to step into the if scope without testing the test value with the mouse then the myString cannot be instanciate with an NullReferenceException throwed.
To get a "functionnal" code I just have to declare myString out of the scope.
I don't undestand why VS cannot let me step over the if test and i will be happy if someone can explain me this strange Exception.
Thanks

EDIT :
After comparison of the two IL code (depending on where the myString declaration is made) i can see that VS "cannot" execute the instruction *newobj* on the hidden class generated and the assignment of the string value is made on null value. In the "out of the scope" declaration version, the *newobj* instruction is made from the begining of the method.

ILCode (inscope):

```
IL_0041:  brtrue.s   IL_006e  // if (test)
IL_0043:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication5.BreakPointTest/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::.ctor()
IL_0048:  stloc.2
IL_0049:  nop
IL_004a:  ldloc.2    
IL_004b:  ldstr      "bli"
IL_0050:  stfld      string ConsoleApplication5.BreakPointTest/'<>c__DisplayClass1'::myString
```

I think that the jump of the pointeur finish on the nop/ldloc.2 instruction, and "forget" the instanciation of the c__DisplayClass1.

Comment: Are you building in release mode by any chance?  The compiler optimizations in release mode can do things to the code that makes the debugging experience a little inconsistent with what you see in the code.

Comment: I tried that code (under the debugger), and it works fine either way for me.

Comment: And works too with the move of the instruction pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a debugger problem. But be aware, that generated code is not at all like the one you've written. You are using myString in a lambda expression, and for that reason compiler created a hidden class that stores a reference to myString. When you are dragging the instruction pointer, necessary initializations of this class could be skipped, because they are not represented in your source.

As an idea, try dragging instruction pointer on the opening bracket after "if".

Comment: Excuse me it's my first question...( the enter key...). I'm building in debug mode without optimisation and when i drag just on open bracket : same result. @Alex : you should have right with the initialization of the hidden class representing the lambda. I'll search in this direction because i don't know well the under cover.